# Removing fills in SWF files

Tags: c#, c++, delphi, flash

guys! I believe I have a different problem.

We have some dozens of SWF files and we need remove a certain fill of each SWF file, to each frame! That fill is purple color and it should help, but we aren't SWF experts.

What we want is developing a tool (in Delphi, C++ or any language) able to read each SWF file and modify it, generating a new version without that purple fill.

We've already downloaded SWF format specification from Adobe website, but it's too huge. If someone have some good idea, we'll please so much.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this movie clip or graphic clip or plain vector? AS 3.0 or AS 2.0?
If you don't have sources of these SWFs you should install some Flash decompiler to check these objects (names of movie clips) - that way would be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least you need a SWF-parsing library because it is very hard work to try to write one yourself.

Here is one in C#:

http://swf.codeplex.com/

For an excellent SWF decompiler tool try:

http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/index.htm

It will let you examine the SWF-files in great detail.